# Re-instantiating a bean

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an executor set up to be invoked via bean.

```
@Configuration
public class ExecutorConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    public ScheduledExecutorService jobExecutor(@Value("${scheduler.jobs}") Integer jobs) {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(jobs);
    }
}
```

I control the shutdown operation of this executor via user input. Once shutdown, this executor will not start back up (no option for restart or submit new tasks).

Hence I want to re-instantiate the bean with a new executor. But only if the existing executor `isShutdown()` (I can check whether its shutdown or not)

How can I achieve this via Spring Boot? Or should I manually create an executor at runtime without the spring way (i.e., create a POJO singleton executor)